# How to create a sticker view for custom chat app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-stickers

How to create a custom sticker view for chat app? Like in iMessages stickers. Draggable sticker view.

Is there any possibility to do it in own chat app.

Comment: use MSSticker class while create stickers

Comment: I didn't get any code, how to use the MSSticker in own chat app. Could you please guide me to achieve the thing.

Comment: I have spend more than a day but i did get any idea.

Comment: My bad i used only for imessage extension , not separately for app.

Comment: Stickers used in [iMessage](https://developer.apple.com/stickers/) really does not need any coding as such. Draggable stickers are provided out of the box without any need for developer to code. If you are looking for code related to this you might not get any. However iMessages do have extension for writing custom iMessage apps, you can create your own using [Message Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages). Do note that **these classes only work with iMessage**. The underlying code might not be available publicly if you are looking for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do the expandable view? like in the same iMessage. I hope from that we can able to customize it.

Comment: As far as I know all of these classes included in Message Framework cannot be used outside. So if you are looking at something similar in your chat application, you might have to end up doing everything. You can think of it like this, Message Framework provides us the container, and we only have control on what goes inside the container. In your case you are looking at reusing the container, which might not be available.